# Can't connect Outlook O365 w Outlook client using MFA

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

My client recently did a switch to 0365 using an MFA client. When I try to setup my account in Office Outlook 365 (the thick client), I get a popup for the MFA login, but apparently it opens the popup in MS Edge and the citrix plugin is not compatible with Edge.

I have my default browser set to Chrome, but apparently Outlook just ignores this setting. I have a later version Edge dev build that uses chromium, but the default older Edge is the one I assume it's trying to use. It doesn't look like I can uninstall it either. Does anyone know if a workaround is possible for this?

If I click the download button in the popup below, it just says goes to a 'Can't Connect' popup

[Outook Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UFAN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some related information of your issue, for your reference:

https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/402071-message-in-edge-about-full-vpn-and-epa/page/2/

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find anything on Citrix about it, thanks for the link, looks like a server side fix only